# Is there a way to switch style in Material Symbols?

Tags: css, google-fonts, google-material-icons

When I use Material Icons, I can switch the style by replacing the class name. (between `material-icons` and `material-icons-outlined`)

Now I am trying to use Material Symbols. Let's say I use star icon and want to make the icon filled.

`public/index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,1,0" />
```

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
star
</span>
```

For Material Symbols, the class name will be the same between filled and outlined and I am wondering if I can switch the style programaitically.

Comment: As I read in the doc, you can set the CSS `font-variation-settings` property per element. Check the codepen example here: [Variable font with Google Fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols#variable_font_with_google_fonts).

Comment: @RenevanderLende Ah I see. I missed there is a property like this.. Thanks for comment. You can post this as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `font-variation-settings` property to set the symbol style per element. Check the codepen example here: [Variable font with Google Fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols#variable_font_with_google_fonts).

I used example code found in [Google: Material Symbols guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols) and modified it to create a little demo showcasing how to set the symbol style using a CSS *custom property*.

- define a CSS *custom property* `--variation`
- modify the custom property with Javascript to hold required `font-variation-settings`
- use the current custom property value in CSS to set required symbol style:

  1. `unset`: sets it to the Google default setting for `.material-symbols-outlined`
  2. *thin style*: `font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 100, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48`
  3. *filled style*: `font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1, 'wght' 700, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48`

**snippet** give the symbol font file time to load...

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
:root      { --variation: unset } /* Sets it to default Google settings */
.icons     { font-variation-settings: var(--variation) } /* Use current settings */
.icons > * { font-size: 3.5rem }
</style>

<fieldset>
    <legend>&nbsp;Icon Style&nbsp;</legend>
    <label for="outline">
        <input id="outline" class="radio" type="radio" name="group" checked
               oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--variation', `unset`);">
        outlined
    </label>
    <label for="thin">
        <input id="thin" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
               oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--variation', `'FILL' 0, 'wght' 100, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48`);">
        thin
    </label>
    <label for="filled">
        <input id="filled" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
               oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--variation', `'FILL' 1, 'wght' 700, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48`);">
        filled
    </label>

    <br><br>

    <div class="icons">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">favorite</span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```